# Pinterest Analytics and Ads API

Tags: pinterest

I am working with Pinterest API currently (https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/?).

I was looking around and I noticed some talk about a a Pintereset Business Insights API and a Pinterest Ads API. From what I can tell they are both exclusive invite only APIs. Is this still true? Is there somewhere I'm not seeing where I can get access to these APIs?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing.

Comment: I'm interested in getting ad performance metrics for my company and our clients. Oddly, the Ads API doesn't seem to offer this ability.